# Assign a category to a text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel table:

[image]

Column B and Column D are given data. I'm looking for formulas for Column E. The logic is that, given a text, we search categories appearing in it: if we find one category, we return it; otherwise, we return an empty string. It is not possible to have 2 categories appearing in one text.

Does anyone know how to write these formulas? That could be single formulas, CSE array formulas or dynamic array formulas.

Comment: You would use `FIND` or `SEARCH` function

Comment: I know... do you have a working solution?

Comment: So B E is there to show it's not possible? Please add your own attempt. It doesn't matter of it's not close to work. Also, what version of Excel have you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell E4 use:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$6,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($D4,"*"&$B$4:$B$6&"*")),0)),"")`

Enter with `ctrl + shift + enter` and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: `{=INDEX($B$4:$B$6;MATCH(1;--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$4:$B$6;D4));0))}` (CSE array formulas) in cell E4, then copy-paste down.